# Scoreboard value in floating text

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to have a scoreboard value in floating text (invisible armor stand with nametag)? I have really no knowledge of scoreboards. I'm using [this generator](https://minecraftcommand.science/hologram-generator).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, change the field where it says CustomName:"Your Text Here" to CustomName:scoreboardnamehere you might have to use quotes CustomName:"scoreboardnamehere" This should work, as it used to in 1.8. Things shouldn't have changed for 1.9.